# I have loose screws - how can I tell a drywall screw apart from a wood screw?

Tags: screws, fastener

Say I have a bunch of screws. Say they are all flat (countersunk) head, phillips drive. They can be different shank/root diameter, with or without a smooth shank, different thread coarseness, color, etc.

They all have a pointy end, about the same angle of point with maybe a small difference in how far from the point the threading ends. They are all magnetic.

**Exhibit A:**
[image]

I know screw #1 is a decking screw and I know that screw #7 is drywall, because that's what the packages said. #6 is brass-color and #8 is gray (and rust), the others being the color they look to be.

Wood screws will generally have a smooth shank at the top, being wood screws, but some (like #9 I think) don't. And a lot of drywall screws are black.

I have a lot of loose screws. How can I determine the types of screws?

Comment: lol .... upvote for making me laugh ..... explanation: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+loose+screw

Comment: please post another picture that shows the head profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drywall screws have a “bugle head”.

Flat head wood screws have a “tapered head”.

This may help:
https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/type-chart.aspx

Comment: This article or image might be more helpful: https://s22293.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/Screen-Shot-2014-05-01-at-10.46.54-AM-297x300.png

https://www.popularwoodworking.com/article/screws-screws-arent/

Comment: there is also a variation  ..... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Grabber-6-1-5-8-in-Philips-Bugle-Head-Drywall-Screws-5-lb-Pack-23175/203111647

Comment: Thanks, all. @jsotola that's what I'm actually seeing a bunch of.